# How automatically calculate time spent in JIRA?

Tags: jira

We would like to configure JIRA so it will automatically calculate time spent for each task based on how long it stays in status (field) «In progress». Does anybody know how we can achieve this?)

Comment: have ou tried the "Time in Status" plugin (https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.obss.plugin.time-in-status/server/overview)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can not be done  just with jira config options. You need a plugin, i.e Time in status, or a script for getting the information you need by code.

If you choose the coding way, you have to use ChangeHistoryManager class and WorklogManager class.

If you need help using this class let us know.

regards